# Python: GUI for Nokia N79 cell phones

Tags: python, user-interface, mobile

Did anybody how to write GUI in Nokia N79 and how ? I mean what packages and something link or tutorial would be helpful. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python for symbain OS is also known as PyS60.
You need to refer to (the only) book -

[**Mobile Python: Rapid prototyping of applications on the mobile platform**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470515058)
[image]

You can find lots of examples from the book itself [here](http://www.mobilenin.com/mobilepythonbook/examples.html).

You can download PyS60 ([SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pys60/files/pys60/1.4.5/PythonForS60_1_4_5_SDK_3rdEdFP1.zip/download)) and install the interpreter on your symbian phone and your PC. (Note: Installing on your PC is not mandatory, but you won't be able to lots of typing on the mobile directly, so you will need it.)

There is a very nice option for bluetooth console, where you can write on the python interpreter on your PC and it would appear on the python interpreter on the phone, in almost real time, via bluetooth.

Note that there seems to be no ongoing development in PyS60 (and there are lots of missing pieces too), so don't expect to be able to do everything using PyS60 (unlike Symbian C++, which is for the same platform with much higher capabilities than PyS60.)

Comment: I downloaded PyS60 (SourceForge) and this might be my stupid question. I really do not know how to install that. Would you mind help me out?

Comment: Find out the OS version of N79 (I think its s60v3 FP2 but confirm, I may be wrong) and install the script shell and SDK of the correponding versions. Install `.sis` files on the phone and `.exe` on  your PC. (Just google about this and you will find lots of useful links.)